# implement sensitivity for device accel data

Tags: algorithm, accelerometer

I have a device which has accelerometer. Device send accel data in x y and z. With those values I am animating ball movement real time. How I can implement sensitivity via software. like mouse sensitivity. If sensitivity is low ball movement will be less, If sensitivity is high ball movement will be large.

My confusion is device will give certain value according to its position. It always gives fixed value for that position, not giving rate of change. How sensitivity is acheived for such cases ?

Can anyone help me with the algorithm / equation on how sensitivity is usually implemented ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be just a multiplier of the output of your accelerometer ? Say you have initial conditions p0 = {x0, y0, z0}. I assume you get the final position by adding the accelerometer output to p0, right?

Comment: just a multiplier may help. but I need a big change. also think of situation: for (x0, y0, z0) gives p0. means every x,y,z has definite p. so it will affect like if sensitivity is high, the ball position we may get will be beyond our position limit. ball will go out of the view area.. and if sensitivity is reduced to very low ball will move only very less, if sensitivity is 0, ball will not move at all. how to handle this

Comment: For the multiplier I think you can just force min/max values whenever the user changes that number. You can also force restrictions on the overall position.. Usually it's done in screen coordinates (x,y)... If the nature of your problem is 3d it might not be as trivial.